# <figure> elements not lining up horizontally when div display is set to inline

Tags: html, css, figure

I'm trying to line up 3 images (each enclosed in its own div tag) horizontally. When I set display: inline in css, I get exactly the result I want.

The problem is when I add a figure tag to each image (so that I can have a figcaption under each image). Now, the 3 images line up vertically, one below the other. How can I fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="projectGallery">
    <div class="projectContainer">
        <figure>
        <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/penguin-clip-art-aiq5zAqiM.png" class="projects" class="projects"/><figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="projectContainer">
        <figure>
        <img src="http://img03.deviantart.net/c670/i/2013/086/5/2/golden_gate_bridge_by_ev_sta-d5zg113.jpg" class="projects"/><figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>  
    </div>
    <div class="projectContainer">
        <figure>
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a6/ee/6f/a6ee6f0db923eb8919803b89f37939ee.jpg" class="projects" class="projects"/><figcaption></figcaption>  
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.projectGallery {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 60px;
}

div.projectContainer {
display: inline;
margin: 20px;
} 

img.projects {
max-width: 20%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9;
border:1px solid #A1B7CC;
}
```

Comment: Use `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Comment: For more clarification why use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline` refer this [**Answer**](http://goo.gl/mzn24E)

Answer (score 0):

to make your div in horizontal position i suggest use

```
display:inline-block
```

In your css edit the `display:inline` into `display:inline-block`

```
div.projectContainer {
display: inline-block;
margin: 20px;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I've tried using inline-block, but the images are still vertically aligned: https://jsfiddle.net/5jv1kgjr/

Comment: There's a lot of peculiar padding around the parent elements because of `max-width` in percentage. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmXxRb?editors=110